# Windows Mobile App will not run more than once

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I'm having problems getting an application I wrote for Windows Mobile 6.0 to run more than one time on my smart phone.

I built it into a .cab and it installs and runs fine the first time, but if I close the application and try to start it again, it will not run unless I restart the phone.

I have checked the task manager after closing the application and it does not show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was in not handling closing the main Form when the application exited from one of the other forms.  Ex: application starts with calculator loaded, user loads unit conversion form from calculator form, and the app hides the calculator.  User then closes the unit form and calculator is still running.

All that I missed was handling an OnClosed event in my main form for when the user tried closing the application from one of the other forms.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that you are closing your application properly? I recommend using a process manager to see if your application still runs on the background.